# Windows 10 upgrade using another partition -- cannot boot up anymore

Tags: ubuntu, windows-8, boot, multi-boot, windows-10-upgrade

I have a dual-boot set up with Ubuntu 14.04, Win 8, and a Storage partition. Since my Win 8 partition is full, I have to choose the Storage partition during the Win 10 upgrade menu.

During the upgrade, after one of the many restarts, I cannot boot into the Win 8 partition from Ubuntu's grub menu anymore. It only shows a purple screen and get stuck.

When I try to boot into Ubuntu partition, there's an error:

```
An error occurred while mounting /media/james/Storage
Press S to skip mounting or M for manual recovery
```

Thus, I suspect the error is due to my choosing the Storage partition during Win 10 upgrade.

When I press M for manual recovery and try to manually mount, there's more information:

```
> mount /media/james/Storage

The disk contains an unclean file system (0, 0).
Metadata kept in WIndows cache, refused to mount.
Failed to mount '/dev/sda4': Operation not permitted
The NTFS partition is in an unsafe state. Please resume and shutdown
Windows fully (no hiberation or fast restarting), or mount the volume
read-only with the 'ro' mount option.
```

What to do in this situation? I can't boot into Windows to fix from that side.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. The advice in this thread solved it for me: 
https://askubuntu.com/questions/722782/unable-to-mount-ntfs-filesystem-after-upgrading-to-windows-10-on-dual-boot-syste

The solution for me was to disable "fast boot" in Windows 10.

More information here: http://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/4189-fast-startup-turn-off-windows-10-a.html

Comment: Please quote the essential parts of the answer from the reference link(s), as the answer can become invalid if the linked page(s) change.